# Clear Cell When Adjacent Cell Equals Value

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with a time-driven trigger that clears a range every week.

This is my current script.

---

```
function clearWeekly() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('OnGoing');
  sheet.getRange('F3:F').clearContent();

}
```

---

I want to update my script so that it clears Column F only where the cell value in Column B  = SMM. Column F consists of checkboxes.

Can someone help here?

You can view my spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r7yjUMdK4eDY328Zeg41pYHTmjHa5slzBLEnVP2GzI8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please make your question more specific by briefly describing your search/research efforts to update your script.

Comment: Hi. I'm guessing that you are in the dark about what to do. In brief, you need to loop through each row, test whether column B = "SMM", and then clear the contents of Column F. [How do I loop through rows to check a value in Google Apps Script](56459074) is a pretty good example that you can adapt to your scenario. If you have a lot of data, then it is not efficient to update the column F value inside the loop, but you can ask about that in another question if it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work using the code below. I used this answer as a reference: [Google sheets loop search for string and clear adjacent cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467239/google-sheets-loop-search-for-string-and-clear-adjacent-cells)

```
function deleteRows() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('OnGoing');
  var lr=sheet.getLastRow()
  var lc=sheet.getLastColumn()
  var a = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lr, lc).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
          if (a[i][1].indexOf("SMM")!= -1){
           var delete1=sheet.getRange(i+3, 6, 1, 23)
           var delete2=sheet.getRange(i+3, 29, 1, 6)
           delete1.clearContent()
           delete2.clearContent()
   }}}
```